# Translate elements inside .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, translation, multilingual, react-i18next

I use the `react-i18next` library in order to translate my react component. It works correctly but not if I use `<Trans>` component inside `.map`. Look at this example:

```
 render() {
    let optionItems = this.state.countries.map(countries =>
        <option key={countries.id}>{countries.name}</option>
      );
    let countriesItems = this.state.countries.map(countries =>
        <option key={countries.id}><Trans>{countries.name}</Trans></option>
      );
      return(
        <div>
            <ul>{optionItems}</ul>
            <div>
                <ul>{countriesItems}</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
```

The first variable `optionItems` displays countries normally, but the second variable `countriesItems` displays only `[object Object]`. I tried replacing {countries.name} with the name of a country but the resulting effect is the same. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post a working example demonstrating the problem somewhere?

Comment: I've never used this library, so I won't venture an answer, but see this from the documentation on how to use with a list: https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component#using-with-lists-v-10-5-0